# How to get my turtles to stay in their pond?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My turtles aren't staying on my pond in Minecraft, and I don't know why. They were born there, I actually bred them and it's the place where they also hatched. But once they are done laying eggs they go far away and do not stay on my really big pond with seagrass, kelp, and with some other fishes.  How can I get the turtle to stay in my pond?

Answer (score 6):

They don't want to.
You already know that turtles remember the block on which they hatch as their home beach, but that doesn't mean that they will always live there. My turtle farm has the same problem, they prefer the sea.

Their behaviour is explained by [Minecraft wikia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Turtle):

> When on land, they generally attempt to move to the nearest water source with direct sky access.
> No matter how far away the turtle is, it always attempts to return to its home beach to lay its eggs after breeding.
> Feeding two turtles seagrass causes them to enter love mode, causing one of the turtles to have eggs in its inventory. The pregnant turtle then travels back to its home beach, which is where it first spawned.

If you want to keep them in your pond you need to trap them, build a fence/wall around it.

Comment: When moving towards the nearest water source, does this utilize the regular mob pathfinding? If so, it would be possible to remove all water sources nearby, leaving the pond as their only option.

Comment: @ginkgo that could be something interesting to test, in my case the farm was near the ocean so no way to remove it.

Comment: Mobs only pathfind to blocks that are within 10 blocks distance, so it might be possible.